# check number between two numbers Android

Tags: android

How can i check if a number is between two other numbers in Android

```
             if(number1.matches("[1024-65535]+"));
                 else{
```

Comment: How are you storing the numbers?

Comment: It involves the `<=` and `>=` operators. If this is seriously above your skill level, you should definitely learn the basics of Java before touching Android...

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to convert all values that need to be compared into `int`s. Then the comparison is trivial.